# how to verify status of TCP Segmentation Offloading

Tags: networking, redhat, linux-networking, ethtool, dmesg

we do the following on linux rhel machines

```
ethtool -K ifcfg-478476 tso off
```

now lets say that we want to verify the settings

how to do the check with ethtool or other cli?

we try

```
ethtool -k ifcfg-478476 | grep -i tso
```

but we not get status

any idea ?

note - `ifcfg-478476` is the eth link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the output of `ethtool -k`, it is called `tcp-segmentation-offload`, not `tso`. The output is like this:

```
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
    tx-tcp-segmentation: on
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: on
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
```